# Using python, how do I get the unique rows from a csv, but get a record of which rows (or value from a row) were combined?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, csv

I have a CSV file that contains 11 columns of data. The first 10 contain information I wish to retain the unique rows from. The last contains filenames for where this information came from.

I want to get only the unique rows from the first 10 and have either a new last column that lists the filenames or alternatively has additional columns with the unstacked filenames.

So for example:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col10 | Filname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | NA | NA | NA | File1 |
| a | 1 | NA | NA | NA | File2 |
| NA | NA | b | NA | NA | File1 |
| NA | NA | b | NA | NA | File3 |
| NA | NA | b | NA | NA | File4 |
| NA | NA | NA | d | 1 | File3 |

goes to:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col10 | Filname1 | Filname2 | Filename3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | NA | NA | NA | File1 | File2 | NA |
| NA | NA | b | NA | NA | File1 | File3 | File4 |
| NA | NA | NA | d | 1 | File3 | NA | NA |

I have been fighting with loops and/or pandas all day.

I tried looping through and adding the unique row, minus the filenames as dictionary keys and appended the filenames to the value, but this seemed to take forever.

I tried to use pivot and unstack from pandas, I even tried combining the first 10 columns and reindexing. But I have not got far.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Oh, I have to use python 2.7

Comment: The silly thing shows the tables correctly formatted when I preview and then mangels them. Any advice on fixing that would be great as well. Cheers,

Comment: try adding an extra line after `So for example:` and `goes to:` or even better, write the csv as comma-separated code so we can reproduce and test

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupby` based on all columns except the filename, and then aggregate filenames with `join` to create a column listing all filenames for each distinct set of other column values:

```
df.groupby(
    df.columns.drop('Filname').to_list(),
    dropna=False)['Filname'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Col2 Col3 Col4  Col10              Filname
0    a   1.0  NaN  NaN    NaN         File1, File2
1  NaN   NaN    b  NaN    NaN  File1, File3, File4
2  NaN   NaN  NaN    d    1.0                File3
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you. 

I think I am using an old version of pandas, but I am loath to update because others in the team may be using the old version. 

I had to remove "_" from to_list and I couldn't get "dropna" to work (bug in this version of pandas), so I replaced the NaN with 0 (value not in data).

Thanks for all your help including tidying my question for me. 

A very elegant solution.

Cheers,